# How to deal with repeated chunks of code in function dealing with dictionaries?

Tags: python, refactoring

I have a nested dictionary from which I am extracting specific information. In some cases, the information I want could be under one of several keys, or maybe not exist.

The code I have written works, but reeks of copy/paste. What is the best way to deal with repeated code chunks, while dealing with potential `KeyError`s?

```py
def getInfo(dic, key):
    info = ""
    
    try:
        info = dic[key]["other_key_1"]
        return "This result " + info
    except KeyError:
        pass 
    
    try:
        info = dic[key]["other_key_2"]
        return "This result " + info
    except KeyError:
        pass 
    
    try:
        info = dic[key]["other_key_3"]
        return "This result " + info
    except KeyError:
        pass
    
    #if they all don't exist
    return "This result " + key
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a generic function, resembling the built-in `dict.get`:

```
def get_first(dct, *keys, default=None):
    for key in keys:
        try:
            return dct[key]
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return default
```

and now your `getInfo` can be reduced to:

```
return 'Result ' + get_first(dct[key], 'one', 'two', 'three', default=key)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I will go for this approach. I've found I've used similar methods in other places, so I think this is the go.

Answer (score 2):

You could store all the possible keys in a list and loop through it.

That way it would also be easier to add new keys to search.

```py
def getInfo(dic, key):
    info = ""
    possible_keys = ["other_key_1", "other_key_2", "other_key_3"]

    for current_key in possible_keys:
        try:
            info = dic[key][current_key]
            return "This result " + info
        except KeyError:
            pass 
    #if they all don't exist
    return "This result " + key
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In this particular function I would use this approach, but I've found similar things in others, and I think the function way is the go.